# How to use ngFor to create elements with children in Bootstrap

Tags: angular, loops, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, ngfor

I have a div that is to be used in a carousel and I have a *ngFor loop with images I want to see how I could get the loop to create a divs with more than one image inside the code is as follows

```
<div class="carousel-item row no-gutters active" *ngFor="let movie of movies">
                <div class="col-3 float-left "><img width="280" class="fluid" [src]="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + movie.poster_path"></div>
                <div class="col-3 float-left "><img width="280" class="fluid" [src]="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + movies.poster_path"></div>
                <div class="col-3 float-left "><img width="280" class="fluid" [src]="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + movies.poster_path"></div>
                <div class="col-3 float-left "><img width="280" class="fluid" [src]="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + movies.poster_path"></div>
            </div>
```

And after that div is created it would create another div with images from the ngFor and so on until the loop is finished this is a jsFiddleLink https://jsfiddle.net/pro2501/8me745h0/3/#&togetherjs=NAgfA0xwsi

Comment: Can you share jsfiddle link?

Comment: @AbdulBasit Hi I have updated it and added a JsFiddle link

Comment: please use stackblitz for Angular. You will love it. Thanks. Just do with static data.

Answer (score 0):

Your `*ngFor` should be on the `div` with the image, like this:

```
<div class="carousel-item row no-gutters active">
  <div class="col-3 float-left" *ngFor="let movie of movies"><img width="280" class="fluid" [src]="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + movie.poster_path"></div>
</div>
```